# JPA usage guidelines /Eclipselink/JPA entity generators

Tags: java, jpa, orm, persistence, eclipselink

I'd like some feedback on the JPA usage in multiple (more than 3) table cases.

1. How do you retreive records from several joined tables? Using JPA Join statement , or by retrieving the Collections
   and iterating and fetching the next set of foreign keyed collections and so on? The second way seems to be a preferred way, but a real pain and also inefficient.
2. The way eclipselink is generating relationships is that there are loads of cascades going on. On top of that even a simple foreign key is set as an obect not as a simple integer id. In other words to extract an X.fk_of_table_Y  I need to call two methods

X.getFKTableY().getFKtableY()

The first function returns an object of the mapped class, and the second one returns the integer.  Oops isn't that too inefficient? Why would you need to load up the object from another table when you just want an id of my own table?

How do you go about it?

1. Do you prefer to  use the methods generated by eclipselink or do you usually code your own? It's basically the same thing as (1) jsut that this one I ask for the eclipselink  context .
2. What tools exist besides EclipseLink to generate the code? In case if I can use my own JPA join queries for relationships (and if that is a good way to do it), I'd like the relationship mapping to be removed from the entity files which EclipseLink won't do.  Is there a tool that only generates  entity classes but not their relationships?
3. If I wish to automate entity generation on a nightly basis (or whenever db changes), via  Eclipselink, what would I have to do? Modify source?

Forgive my English,I can write a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the short reply, this is from a phone. First, it is possible in EclipseLink to have both the integer id of the FK and the object itself as differrent properties; simply give both the same column name, but mark only one of them as updateable and insertable. You will be able to set the relation with one of the properties but not both.

Secondly, I use both the entity mappings and DAO objects with complex JPA queries to access entities, the difference being that I use the queries for multiple joins and aggregation funcctions or when prefetching is needed, and I use the entity mappings when traversing the entity graph. Still, benchmarking is needed everywhere - I've had a complex query that was faster (60ms vs 300ms) when decomposed into the entity mappings.

Comment: Thanks man... sorry my reputation is not enough to give you a positive point. I'll wait for some more answers and vote one of them:)

Comment: Tassos, how do I make two columns ?I'm using eclipselink in Netbeans but if there is an option to change it, I'm happy to install it to eclipse again and try. I don't see any option which of course is because I don't know the tool that well.

Comment: What you do is you have f.e. `int personId` and `Person person` as members, but you give them both the same database column name using `@Column(name="PERSON_ID")` and `@JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")`. However, you will need to add `updateable=false, insertable=false` to one of the two properties (I prefer the int personally).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Not sure my manager will allow me though because we are trying to automate the entity generation  on every db change through eclipselink. This process seems to be manual.